# Finding a square side length is R in 2D plane ?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm

I was at the high frequency Trading firm interview, they asked me

Find a square whose length size is R with given n points in the 2D plane

conditions:

--parallel sides to the axis
and it contains at least 5 of the n points

running complexity is not relative to the R

they told me to give them O(n) algorithm

Comment: so how did you respond?

Comment: Is R given to you ahead of time or are you allowed to select it?

Comment: this must be more missing here.  The problem posed (assuming R given) may have no solution.

Comment: @george that would proably be an acceptable result of the algorithm (find a solution or determine that none exist in O(n) time). I believe the difficult (or impossible) part is the linear time complexity (assuming the points are given as, say, an unsorted list).

Comment: @george ya I really did not have a clear answer I messed it up

Comment: @jerry R is  not given but they told me running time does not depend on R

Comment: correct answer, "this question is ambiguously written and either trivial or impossible depending on interpretation".

Comment: It dawned on me that the question isn't clear if the complexity requirment applies to time, space, or both. Is it just time?

Answer (score 4):

Interesting problem, thanks for posting!  Here's my solution.  It feels a bit inelegant but I think it meets the problem definition:

Inputs: `R`, `P = {(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1), ..., (x_N-1, y_N-1)}`

Output: `(u,v)` such that the square with corners `(u,v)` and `(u+R, v+R)` contains at least 5 points from `P`, or NULL if no such `(u,v)` exist

Constraint: asymptotic run time should be `O(n)`

Consider tiling the plane with `RxR` squares.  Construct a sparse matrix, `B` defined as

```
B[i][j] = {(x,y) in P | floor(x/R) = i and floor(y/R) = j}
```

As you are constructing `B`, if you find an entry that contains at least five elements stop and output `(u,v) = (i*R, j*R)` for `i,j` of the matrix entry containing five points.

If the construction of `B` did not yield a solution then either there is no solution or else the square with side length `R` does not line up with our tiling.  To test for this second case we will consider points from four adjacent tiles.

Iterate the non-empty entries in `B`.  For each non-empty entry `B[i][j]`, consider the collection of points contained in the tile represented by the entry itself and in the tiles above and to the right.  These are the points in entries: `B[i][j], B[i+1][j], B[i][j+1], B[i+1][j+1]`.  There can be no more than 16 points in this collection, since each entry must have fewer than 5.  Examine this collection and test if there are 5 points among the points in this collection satisfying the problem criteria; if so stop and output the solution. (I could specify this algorithm in more detail, but since (a) such an algorithm clearly exists, and (b) its asymptotic runtime is `O(1)`, I won't go into that detail).

If after iterating the entries in `B` no solution is found then output NULL.

The construction of `B` involves just a single pass over `P` and hence is `O(N)`.  `B` has no more than `N` elements, so iterating it is `O(N)`.  The algorithm for each element in `B` considers no more than 16 points and hence does not depend on `N` and is `O(1)`, so the overall solution meets the `O(N)` target.

Comment: +1 -- you cant skip the empty b[i][j] though - a solution could very well have a lower left corner in an empty box.

Comment: @george - nice catch!  we can include additional tiles from B[i-1][j], B[i-1][j+1] to address this and still keep the asymptotic performance we want.

Comment: +1 I had a similar idea last night, but you have to be careful with `B` to ensure complexity that is both O(n) and independent of `R`. `B` probably has to be a rectangular array so that allocation and the accesses to check adjacent tiles can occur in constant time. Using an initial pass to find the bounds, the array will have `ceil((maxX-minX)/R)*ceil((maxY-minY)/R)` elements. To avoid checking if each one is empty, keep an unsorted list of which tile each of the n points was placed into and iterate over that.

Answer (score 1):

Run through set once, keeping the 5 largest x values in a (sorted) local array. Maintaining the sorted local array is O(N) (constant time performed N times at most).

Define xMin and xMax as the x-coordinates of the two points with largest and 5th largest x values respectively (ie (a[0] and a[4]).

Sort a[] again on Y value, and set yMin and yMax as above, again in constant time.

Define deltaX = xMax- xMin, and deltaY as yMax - yMin, and R = largest of deltaX and deltaY.

The square of side length R located with upper-right at (xMax,yMax) meets the criteria.

Observation if R is fixed in advance:

- O(N) complexity means no sort is allowed except on a fixed number of points, as only a Radix sort would meet the criteria and it requires a constraint on the values of xMax-xMin and of yMax-yMin, which was not provided.
- Perhaps the trick is to start with the point furthest down and left, and move up and right. The lower-left-most point can be determined in a single pass of the input.
- Moving up and right in steps and counitng points in the square requries sorting the points on X and Y in advance, which to be done in O(N) time requiress that the Radix sort constraint be met.

Comment: This won't work. Counter example: the points are `{(100,0),(99,1),(99,2),(101,1),(101,2),(0,100),(1,99),(2,99),(1,101),(2,101)}`. Then `ax[0]=ay[0]=101`, `ax[4]=ay[4]=99`, `deltaX=2`, and `deltaY=2`. However, the axis aligned square with side length 2 whose upper right corner is at `(101,101)` does not contain any of the given points. Also, I took the OP's question to mean R was a constant given ahead of time. I'll ask for clarification.

Comment: Are you allowed to define R?  I would assume that's intended to be a fixed input, otherwise you can easily make it big enough to cover everything.

Comment: @jerry: Don't reselect the points for y, use the original 5 points with largest x and resort those five points on y. for your example that gives deltaX = 101-2 = 99, deltaY = 101, R = 101.

Comment: @Tim: But R must still be finite, and you still need to locate it on the plane.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but you seem to be computing a value of R, whereas I took it to be supplied as an argument.  Of course, if the supplied value of R is too small, there will be no solution.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I see I misread your answer, sorry. This will work assuming you can choose R but you're not trying to optimize its value. If that's the case, however, why not just use the first five point you enumerate? That algorithm runs in O(1) time.

Comment: given R, function should return false or true.